# Para que serve Serialize e Deserialize?

Tags: c#, api

Minha dúvida é para que serve que **Serialize** e **Deserialize** em C#.
Eu tenho uma API e estou tendo alguns problemas com esta questão, então quero entender melhor.

Comment: A  sua pergunta não está clara, edite e explique melhor, qual API você está utilizando? O que é esse "Serialize" e "Deserialize" dentro dessa API? São métodos? Precisamos de mais informações para podermos ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com o Serialize, voce cria uma serie de dados, por exemplo um JSON.

Voce pode serializar uma lista List em um JSON pra retornar pra um pagina e preencher um grid de dados via javascript, por exemplo.

O mesmo acontece ao contrario, voce "deserializa" um JSON para uma lista List

Comment: É comum fazer este processo de deserialização ao fazer um post na API?

Comment: Não sei responder se é comum fazer esse processo... Por ser um desenvolvedor independente, não tenho muito contato com outros Devs e acabei adotando alguns métodos de trabalho próprios, entretanto a meu ver é o mais simples pra lidar com dados vindos de um JSON.

Entretato todos os campos do JSON devem estar com o tipo de dado certo pro tipo que irá recebe-lo, você só deve se atentar a isso pra não ter problemas durante a conversão.

Answer (score 1):

Serialize é o processo de transformar um objeto em um stream de bytes! Um exemplo é pegar um List<> e transformar ele em um JSON para manipular em algum lugar e depois transforma-lo em uma List novamente.